# I need help to get URL with Regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I extract the link from a CSS rule, so that if I do

```
string1 = "background-image: url(hi.jpg);"
string2 = "background-image: url(hi.jpg)"
string4 = @"background-image: url("hi.jpg")"
string5 = @"background-image: url("hi.jpg"); display:none"
string6 = "background-image: url('hi.jpg')"
string7 = "background-image: url('hi.jpg');"
```

How can I make a function that uses regex to extract the link value from the given string regardless of whether the string is in double or single quotes or whether it has a semicolon or not;

Example:

```
getUrl(string1); // outputs:  hi.jpg
getUrl(string2); // outputs:  hi.jpg
getUrl(string3); // outputs:  hi.jpg
getUrl(string4); // outputs:  hi.jpg
getUrl(string5); // outputs:  hi.jpg
getUrl(string6); // outputs:  hi.jpg
getUrl(string7); // outputs:  hi.jpg
```

I have tried the following but didn't work for me:

```
private string getUrl(string input) {
    return Regex.Match(input, @"(?<=\().+?(?=\))").Value;
}
```

**EDIT:**
The method above only work correctly if there were NO QUOTES. How can get it to work if there are single or double quotes as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<=\()['"]?(.+?)['"]?(?=\))
```

You can try this.Grab the capture or group 1.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/24